# Airflow pass output of task to Postgres Operator

Tags: airflow

I have an Airflow TaskFlow task that returns output:

```py
@task
def extract(**context):
    return { "json": "values" }
```

How do I pass that to the Postgres Operator?

```py
load = PostgresOperator(
  task_id="load",
  postgres_conn_id="dbt",
  sql="sql/load.sql",
  parameters={ """ <response here>  """}
)

extract() >> load()
```

Should I use `psycopg` in the extract task and save it to the db? It's just a few kBs of a json string. Then run `dbt` in other tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added a `pg_hook` in my extract task to do both extract and load

```py
@task
def extract(**context):
    response = { "json": "values" }
    sql = f"INSERT INTO my_table(data) VALUES(%s);"
    pg_hook.run(sql, parameters=(json.dumps(response)))
```